# Compile issue with scala generics

Tags: scala, generics

```
object PDJcrCache {
  val cache = new ConcurrentHashMap[String, _ <: PDEntity]()

  def put[A <: PDEntity](elem: A) = {
    cache.put(elem.asInstanceOf[PDEntity].getId, ***elem***)
  }
  def get[A <: PDEntity](id: String): A = {
    cache.get(id).asInstanceOf[A]
  }
  def remove[A <: PDEntity](id: String) = {
    cache.remove(id)
  }
}
```

I am getting a compile error at 
`cache.put(elem.asInstanceOf[PDEntity].getId, ***elem***)`.
It says `expected _$1, actual A`. Any idea about this issue?
Also is this the correct way to use Scala generics?

Comment: Why do you need `elem.asInstanceOf[PDEntity].getId`... you can do.. `elem.getId` Also... why do you need `_ <: PDEntity` in your HashMap signature... you can as well use just `PDEntity`.... everything else stays the same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ConcurrentHashMap[String, _ <: PDEntity]` is a map whose values are of type "some unknown subtype of `PDEntity`". So you can't put `elem` into such a map, because `A` might be a different subtype of `PDEntity` from the particular subtype that that map uses.

You probably want a `ConcurrentHashMap[String, PDEntity]`, though to be honest most of your generics look unnecessary - if you just want to store and retrieve `PDEntity`s, why not just keep them as that? If you want a cache of some specific subtype of `PDEntity` then `A` should be a type parameter on the class, not on the individual methods. What is it you're trying to achieve?